# C# WPF SelectionChangedIndex Term

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

So my source has GetterSetter.cs and it has some props which is

```
public string ShowName { get; set; }
```

and then I have this on my mainwindow.cs

```
List<GetterSetter> showList = new List<GetterSetter>();
```

and I wanna change textBox when user clicked an item from listView
in old Windows Form that code did work

```
showNameBox.Text = showList(listView.SelectedItems[0].Index).ShowName;
```

but now I can't say .Index and also it says

> Non-invocable member 'MainWindow.showList' cannot be used like a method.

for showList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a typo, please try:

```
showNameBox.Text = showList[listView.Items.IndexOf(listView.SelectedItems[0])].ShowName;
```

Comment: now showlist error is gone but I still cant do .Index I tried without it but it didnt work :( and the error is 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Index'